# How to convert ajax json post request from Jquery to Python/Django dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to convert an AJAX request retrieving JSON from JS to Python's dictionary in Django, but unsuccessfully. Please help.

This is the original JS code:

```
myJSON = JSON.stringify(myJsObject);

// POST - send JSON data to Python/Django server
$.ajax({
  url: "/savemyexposuresituation",
  type: "POST",
  datatype: 'json',
  data: myJSON,
  async: false,
  success: function() {
    alert('Your data is saved :)');
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('Error occured :(');
  }
});
}
```

This is the Django side:

```
def saveExposureSituation(request):

#get es data - JSON file
fromJs = request.POST

fromJs = json.loads(fromJs)
```

All I get is `JSON object must be string, not QueryDict`. I tried to convert this QueryDict to something else unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 3 to convert byte to strings you need to use `decode("utf-8")`. So may be to something like this `request.POST.decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST` is for form-encoded data. You should be using `request.body`.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried. Now it says "json object must be string, not bytes".

Comment: Ok. I figured out now. I needed this: fromJs = fromJs.decode('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to responses, the complete answer would be:

```
def saveExposureSituation(request):

    fromJs = request.body
    fromJs = fromJs.encode('utf-8')

    #now we can load our JSON from JS
    fromJs = json.loads(fromJs)
```